# The chariot race

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

In a chariot race only **4 cars came to the finish: the blue, the green, the red and the white one.**

Titus, who is in bed with a cold, inquires to Quintus about the outcome of the race, because he only knows rumors:

> **1.** The blue has finished fourth.
>   **2.** The green is first become.
>   **3.** The red did not become fourth.
>   **4.** The white did not become first or fourth.

***"Three of these rumors are true and one is wrong,"*** says Quintus.

From this concludes Titus, which
car is first and which fourth, and indeed ...

> (A) the green and the blue.
>    (B) the green and the red.
>    (C) the white and the blue.
>    (D) the green and the white.
>    (E) the red and the blue.

Comment: So, what is the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the statements

> 1) Blue is 4, 2) Green is 1, 3) Red is 1,2,or 3, 4) White is 2 or 3,

So

> if statement 3 is False, then Red is 4 and Statement 1 is False, too.  This can't be, so Statement 3 is True

And

> if statement 4 is false, then White is 1 or 4 and statement 1 or 2 is false.  This can't be so Statement 4 is True

And

> if statement 1 is false,  then Green must be 1, Red and white must be 2 and 3 and blue  has no where to go, so statement 1 is true.

Thus

> Statement 2 is false.  So 4 must be Blue and 1 must be red

So

> E is the right answer